# How can i redirect only ios uiwebview with htaccess?

Tags: ios, .htaccess

I can redirect based on user agent. But because of some weird problems on this work i am doing, i need to only redirect in-app uiwebviews to a sub folder or domain. Mobile Safari should be out of this redirect. Need help...

Answer (score 0):

You can change the user agent of the in-app web views by writing to the standard user defaults with the "UserAgent" key. Here is an example,

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:@{
     @"UserAgent": @"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/536.26.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.2 Safari/536.26.17"}];
```

Comment: This is the problem. I am not the developer of the ios app. I am writing the new web app for them but because of some problems it will take some time to change the ios app. Therefore i am trying to solve it in web part. The ios app is only a wrapper around html5 web app. I am going to move it to a subfolder and trying to redirect app users to there. I know it is a bad solution but, still there is nothing i can do about the app.